# Move from Screen in BottonTabNavigator to other Screen

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I'm new into React Native and I have this question: I have a *createBottomTabNavigator* in which I have 2 buttons (*MainComponent.js*):

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createBottomTabNavigator } from '@react-navigation/bottom-tabs';
import { createNativeStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/native-stack';
import HomeScreen from './HomeScreen';
import DetailsScreen from './DetailsScreen';

//Screen names
const homeName = 'Discover';
const detailsName = 'Chats';

const Tab = createBottomTabNavigator();

<NavigationContainer>
    <Tab.Navigator>
      <Tab.Screen
        name={homeName}
        component={HomeScreen}
      />
      <Tab.Screen
        name={detailsName}
        component={DetailsScreen}
      />
    </Tab.Navigator>
  </NavigationContainer>
```

When I navigate to the HomeScreen, for example, I want to have a button that makes the user go to another screen independent of this navigation component. I'm trying to do this (*HomeScreen.js*):

```
  export default function HomeScreen({ navigation }) {
  const handlePress = () => {
    navigation.navigate('Play'); // Use the screen name registered in your navigator
  };
  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
      <TouchableOpacity style={styles.button} onPress={handlePress}>
        <Text style={styles.text}>Meet People!</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    </View>
  );
}
```

But this throws this error:

*The action 'NAVIGATE' with payload {"name":"Play"} was not handled by any navigator.
Do you have a screen named 'Play'?
If you're trying to navigate to a screen in a nested navigator, see https://reactnavigation.org/docs/nesting-navigators#navigating-to-a-screen-in-a-nested-navigator.
This is a development-only warning and won't be shown in production.*

How would you do this then??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would have to make the homeName component a stack not a single screen, the stack will contain both the homescreen and you will create another playscreen which will be in the same stack
https://reactnavigation.org/docs/stack-navigator/